# solving a stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

This is exercise 5.6 from SDE by Oksendal.

solve:

$dY_t=rdt+ \alpha Y_tdB_t$

Where $r,\alpha $ are real constants and $B(t)$ is a 1-dimensional Brownian motion.

The book has a hint for this problem,but I can't solve it yet.

Is there any other hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Another hint besides the hint you were given that we don't know what it is?  I dunno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint given by the book is to multiply the equation by the *integrating factor* $$
F_t = \exp\left(-\alpha B_t + \alpha^2t/2\right)
$$
So the new SDE will be
$$
F_tdY_t = rF_tdt + \alpha Y_t dB_t
$$
Continuing analogy with the integrating factor, can you check if there is an easy way to write the RHS as $dg(Y_t,t)$?

Comment: would you pls explain more?I'm new to SDE.

Comment: @user115608 do you know how to solve 1st order usual ODEs with method of integrating factor?

Comment: You should multiply all terms with the same factor.

Comment: @user115608 : A systematic way to use the integrating factor is to consider the (Ito-) derivative of $F_t·Y_t$.

Comment: For $Z=FY$ I get $dZ=rFdt $ so that $$Y_t=F_t^{-1}(Y_0+r\int_0^tF_sds),$$ based on $dF=α^2dt-αdB$.

Comment: @LutzL yes.i did